# Jquery cycle2 plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I am having trouble getting the jquery cycle2 plugin to work.

The slideshow doesn't load and the images.  They just appear 1 underneath each other.  I don't see any console errors. I have the latest jquery(3.0).

Here is my code.  By the way, I am relatively new to javascript and jquery :

```js
$('document').ready(function($) {
  $('#slideshow').cycle({
    timeout: 0, // no autoplay
    fx: 'fade', //
    next: '#next',
    prev: '#prev'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
  <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo      get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Cycle2 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo     get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/scripts/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div id="slideshow">
  <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:red;"></div>
  <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:blue;"></div>
  <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:green;"></div>
  <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:yellow;">
  </div>
  <div id="prev" style="float:left;">PREV</div>
  <div id="next" style="float:right;">NEXT</div>
```

I am not sure why this isn't working.  As this is an example that was previously given by someone.  I am using wordpress by the way.  It is not working in chrome nor firefox.

Comment: Most themes already include jQuery.js. You should be using proper `enqueue_script` method. Best guess is second version wipes out plugin you load ... but that should also throw error. As for images stacking... use default css to fix that

Comment: Hi,  If I remove the jquery.js from head, I get a console error "jquery" is not defined, and that error is coming from the cycle plugin, which is declaring jquery.  And the images stacking should need be with css, the plugin itself it supposed to create a slideshow.

Comment: But that's why you should enqueue properly...is there another jQuery.js in page? You can't include a plugin file before jQuery.js loads and if it loads twice it will wipe out plugins registered to first version

Comment: Hi, I am relatively new to javascript and website development in general so I hope I understood you correctly.  There is no other jquery.js/jquery.min.js in the header being loaded.  I registered the script in the functions.php of my theme with this code

Comment: function wpb_adding_styles() {
wp_register_script('my_script_name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/jquery.cycle2.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script_name');
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles' );

Comment: I appreciate your help by the way

Comment: Scripts may also be in `<body>` after all content and before closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any other jquery scripts being loaded.  Furthermore, wouldn't that give an error in the console?

Comment: OK... just trying to be certain

Comment: "I have the latest jquery(3.0)." *posts code with link to some older version*

Comment: LOL, I just changed the code to see if an older jquery would work and forgot to change it back

Answer (score 1):

Its because you haven't specified which child HTML element you need to cycle through. Please add `data-cycle-slides="> div"` to your markup.

[Documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php):

> Cycle2 allows you to use any type of element for the slides, it's not
>   solely for cycling images. However, images are the default slide type
>   so to use other elements you need to override the slides option as
>   show on this page. The slides option can be set to any valid jQuery
>   selector. The default value is > img which is a selector to find all
>   image elements that are immediate children of the slideshow container.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/tf24noy6/

Snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cycle2 Plugin - Malsup by codeandcloud</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
    <title>Cycle2 Plugin - Malsup by codeandcloud</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[

        $('document').ready(function ($) {
            $('#slideshow').cycle({
                timeout: 0, // no autoplay
                fx: 'fade', //
                next: '#next',
                prev: '#prev'
            });
        });

        //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 250px">
        <div id="slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div">
            <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:red;"></div>
            <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:blue;"></div>
            <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:green;"></div>
            <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:yellow;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="prev" style="float:left;">PREV</div>
        <div id="next" style="float:right;">NEXT</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Naveen, but this is not working for me either.  The result I get is if you take your fiddle and change the language to "Javascript 1.7" and then run.  I am using the latest version of chrome.

Comment: jquery is a *JavaScript* library. You need to include jQuery because, cycle2 is a *jQuery plugin* and it depends on jquery.

Comment: Hi Naveen, thank you for the help but I do not understand.  I thought I included jquery as you can see in the header.  I have the appropriate file in the folder.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo      get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: remove `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` from page top. above `header`

Comment: Hi naveen.  I did that already.  The editor put that in, not I.

Comment: are you sure that you are placing the `$('#slideshow').cycle` inside the head tag or in the body tag after the element `div id="slideshow"` close tag?

Comment: The div id slideshow is in the body.  The $('#slideshow').cycle was placed right before the /body.

Comment: Naveen, sorry to bother you but I have gotten the script to load.  Turns out I was missing one letter in my function.  I have an additional issue.  Now I get a console error: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector.  Would you be familiar with this?